# Duplicates in Associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

My foreach is entering an array in the second level of my $bad_email array, something like this

```
["vlley@.rsr.com"] { ["name"]=>  "Woo Hilley", ["amount"]=> "125.16"}
["vey@.rsr.com"] { ["name"]=>  "Shoo Moo", ["amount"]=> "12.16"}
```

If I try to enter the same value like `["vlley@.rsr.com"] { ["name"]=>  "Woo Hilley", ["amount"]=> "125.16"}` again I want it to run specific code.  Im not sure how to fix this. The code Im running seems to work when the name is the same but I want the email, name and amount to all match before it fires. Help please

```
$bad_email = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($id_array as $key => $id) {            
    $bad_email[$email][name] =$name;
    $bad_email[$email][amount] = $amount;
    if ($bad_email[$email][$amount], $bad_email[$email])) {
        // DO CODE HERE!!!!
        $i++;
    }
}
```

`$email`, `$name`, and `$amount` are all pulled from an api call

Comment: Do you have a reason why the `$bad_email` array must b numerically indexed by `$i`?  If you used the email address as the array key, it would become simple to test.

Comment: no reason, I only want to make it work

Comment: Do all three have to match, or does an email address indicate a unique entry? In other words, do you need to verify the combination of `email/name/amount` so that the same email could have two different names?

Comment: I need the combo of all 3 to match, not just the email.

Comment: How are you populating `$email,$name,$amount`? Looks like some relevant code has been omitted.

Comment: I actually only need the email and amount to match.  I'll update my code

Comment: Still need to know where in the loop `$email,$name,$amount` were defined.

Comment: I make a call to the api outside the foreach loop.  I am putting them into an array like this `$id_array =$transaction->_ids;`.  Then inside the foreach i am pulling the info like $transaction = API::find($id); then $amount = $transaction->amount

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to do. Please clarify your question, especially the first phrase.

Answer (score 0):

This worked...

```
$bad_email = array();
$temp_email = array();

foreach ($id_array as $key => $id) {            
            $temp_email =$bad_email;


            $bad_email[$email][name] =$name;
            $bad_email[$email][amount] = $amount;
            if ($bad_email[$email][amount] == $temp_email[$email][amount]){ 
                 // DO CODE HERE!!!!


        }
    }


}
```